# Is there an easy way to create a CLI "shortcut" arg that implements other args using Python's `argparse`?

Tags: python, arguments, command-line-arguments, argparse

Is there an *easy* way to make a CLI arg "shortcut" (for lack of a better term) using `argparse`? I also can't think of a better term to try and search for implementations...

Basically I'm trying to make something similar to rsync's `--archive` option:

[image: rsync's --archive option]

#### Example

Let's assume I have a python3 program that uses argparse for CLI parsing:

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-x", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("-y", action=argparse.BooleanOptionalAction)
parser.add_argument("--foobar")
args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
```

I'd like to add a `--shortcut` arg that is equivalent to `-x -y --foobar BAZ`. These two would result in the same functionality:

```bash
python foo.py -x -y --foobar BAZ
python foo.py --shortcut
```

Right now what I'm doing is basically:

```py
# ... all the parser.add_argument() calls ...
args = parse.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
if args.shortcut:
    args.x = True
    args.y = True
    args.foobar = "BAZ"
```

The above works decently well, but (a) it is hard to maintain because I have to update docstrings and this `if args.shortcut` separately and (b) the precedence logic gets very complicated when dealing with overrides.

The requirement is:

- `--shortcut --foobar FOO` parses as `x=True, y=True, foobar=FOO`
- `--foobar FOO --shortcut` parses as `x=True, y=True, foobar=BAR`
- `--foobar FOO --shortcut --foobar FOO` parses as `x=True, y=True, foobar=FOO`

`argparse` already handles order precedence for me, but not with the `--shortcut` arg.

Comment: Can you not just default the values of parameters using argparse or does that not sole the problem?

Comment: The actual program has ~20 CLI options. All of them are already set to reasonable defaults, but there are cases were it's common to always set 3 to 5 different args simultaneously (though it still possible to use one or some individually).

Answer (score 2):

One pretty reliable way is to pre-process `argv` and replace any "shortcut" args with their CLI equivalent.

This allows us to rely on `argparse`'s precedence logic and we don't have to mess with anything there. We can also record the shortcut in a module variable and use it in the arg docstring.

Special thanks to Murali Ganapathy for their suggestion here!

```py
CLI_SHORTCUT = [
    "-x",
    "-y",
    *["--foobar", "BAR"],  # splatting makes it obvious what params go with an arg.
]

...
parser.add_argument("--foobar", help=f"Alias for '{' '.join(CLI_SHORTCUT)}'")
...

def preprocess_arvg(cli_args: Sequence[str]) -> Iterator[str]:
    """Preprocess sys.argv, replacing any "shortcut" commands with their equivalent args.

    Args:
        cli_args: The args passed via command line as a sequence of strings.
    """
    for arg in cli_args:
        # We append the original arg so that the parsed Namespace object
        # sets that 'shortcut' value correctly.
        if arg in {"-s", "--shortcut"}:
            yield from CLI_SHORTCUT + [arg]
        # elif arg == "--fake":  # add any other shortcuts here
        #    yield from OTHER_CLI_SHORTCUT + [arg]
        else:
            yield arg

# argv[1:] = ["--shortcut"]
preprocessed_argv = list(preprocess_arvg(sys.argv[1:]))
# preprocessed_argv = ["-x", "-y", "--foobar", "BAR", "--shortcut"]
argparse.parse_args(preprocessed_argv)
# argparse.Namespace(x=True, y=True, foobar="BAR", shortcut=True)

## --help renders as:
#  --shortcut         Alias for '-x -y --foobar BAR'
```

Comment: If you use `ArgumentParser(fromfile_prefix_chars='@')` https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#fromfile-prefix-chars, You could use `python foo.py @shortcut`, where `shortcut` file as the desired strings.